# Using two array in single for each loop

Tags: vb.net, split

In my application i have string like this `1,2,3&&4,5,6`. Now i want check each and every element in single for each loop. Is it possible or not? If its possible how can i acheive this?.

Am trying using `split` method. But if i am using `split` method i want more than loop.

Like

```
dim sa as string=1,2,3&&4,5,6

for each x as string in sa.split("&&")
  for each y as string in x.split(",")
    ''' Here My Process
  next
next
```

How can over come this?. how can change to single loop?. It is possible or not?.

Comment: I'm confused as to what exactly you are trying to do, are you only interested in the integer values? Is this the only string that needs parsed? any more info would help

Comment: Please see my updated answer. You will like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String.Split` has an overload that accepts an array of string delimiters:

```
Dim input As String = "1,2,3&&4,5,6"
For Each element As String In input.Split({",", "&&"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
  'do your processing on (1,2,3,4,5,6)
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, you want to use only one `for each` instead of using `for each` in `for each`.

You can first split by "&&" and then join with ",":

```
dim sa as string=1,2,3&&4,5,6
dim stringArray = String.Join(",", sa.split("&&")).split(",")

for each x as string in stringArray
end for
```

Comment: Ingenious but not too efficient. I think that using regular expressions is a good habit to get into.

Comment: @Bathsheba: so you think regex is super-efficient? :)

Comment: Probably not if Microsoft implemented the parser ;-)

Comment: @Bathsheba: Any universal processing is generally worse in performance than any specific implementation. If you provided performance analysis in your answer, and your regex is faster, we could talk about efficiency. :)

Comment: Extensibility is, for me, the most important issue here. What happens if the string contains another delimiter type? Who's code would be harder to change? Splitting on RegEx is second nature in Java so let's get used to it.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Maintainability and efficiency are two different things, often going in opposite directions of each other. So the more you get one, the more you lose the other.

Answer (score 0):

You could split using a *regular expression* as a delimiter:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions 'goes at the top of the module

For Each x As String In Regex.Split(sa, "\,|&&")
```

Where the regular expression means "comma or two ampersands". Note that you need to 'escape' the comma using a backslash; this is because commas do something special in regular expressions.

Don't forget to enclose your string in quotes:

```
dim sa as string="1,2,3&&4,5,6"
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to split on the "," and the "&" via the `Split` method and ignore empty entries, as such:

```
Dim sa As String = "1,2,3&&4,5,6"
Dim split As String() = sa.Split(New Char() {",", "&"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

For Each value In split
    Debug.WriteLine(value)
Next
```